# Wrong search result in a file through Bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am searching an event field in a file but is giving wrong output. I am searching gpio-keys event in input devices for which I have written a script, but I'm unable to print anything in output file (in my case I am writing in a button device file it is null always). Please help me to figure out this. Where am I doing wrong in script file?

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

  if  grep -q  "gpio-keys" /proc/bus/input/devices  ; then
    EVENT=$(cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep "Handlers=kbd")
    foo= `echo $EVENT | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="evbug")printf($(i-1))}'`
    #foo=${EVENT:(-7)}
    echo -n $foo > /home/ubuntu/Setups/buttonDevice
 fi
```

Comment: `foo= …` is not assigning anything to `$foo`.

Comment: Tip: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: This should be possible with a single `awk`, can you show a relevant part of your input file?

Comment: Hello Biffien Thnaks for your quick reply. You are right foo is not getting assigned but my task is to assign it with second field of Handlers=kbd line in gpio-keys section. In my case Handlers=kbd event0. I want event0 in foo by making my script generic. Please look at the link i have attahed files at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bE79oCzeVoKWxQxVKmsufQu1aUrfUq1Q. file.txt is nothing but list of input devices at /proc/bus/input location.

Comment: hello cdarke please help me figure out. files are avaliable at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bE79oCzeVoKWxQxVKmsufQu1aUrfUq1Q location.

Comment: @AtmaPrakash (Please use `@` when responding to a specific user.) All code should go in the question, not via some iffy links. And it should preferably be a [mcve].

Comment: What do you want to happen if none of the `Handlers=kbd` events contain the string `evbug`? Or does the presence of `gpio-keys` mean that's always going to be there?

Answer (score 1):

Prakash, I don't have access to your google drive. But I just want to give you some suggestion:-

```
foo= `echo $EVENT | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="evbug")printf($(i-1))}'`
```

This is old style now. Better use like below:-

```
foo=$(echo $EVENT | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="evbug")printf($(i-1))}')
```

Also always use double quotes "" when echoing a variable. See below:-

```
echo -n "$foo" > /home/ubuntu/Setups/buttonDevice
```

Try with the below code it will work for you

```
#!/bin/bash

 if  grep   "gpio-keys" /proc/bus/input/devices >/dev/null ; then
    cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep "Handlers=kbd" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i ~ /eve/){printf "%s \n", $i} } }') > /home/ubuntu/Setups/buttonDevice
 fi
```

The output in buttonDevice would be

> event0
>   event1
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   event100

Comment: It's not only old style. The blank after equal sign makes the assignment fail and is a bug. And shouldn't you quote "$EVENT" then, too?

Comment: @userunknown, True. Thanks

Comment: Hello Abhijit thanks for your reply i am still not able to get anything in  buttondevce by using your code also. 
my task is to search gpio-keys event name to foo so i can read it any time when any interrupt come to mapped gpio event.

Comment: Hi Prakash, can you modify your question and provide some sample information in your device file and what exactly you are trying to do. Just add one more line echo "$EVENT" and check what it print and let me know. I will fix your problem.

Comment: hello abhijit please look at the link i have just uploaded at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WspxXKljG8pOQPpb4eL91eepvRkbC4lFHXUfGEKoYzk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: do you need just to print `event0` in `buttonDevice` file?

Comment: yes. But There are two Handlers-kbd field so i want to print only gpio-keys Handlers event. I my case it is event0 but it may vary also depends on how kernel allows. Thanks

Comment: Will this field always come as 3rd column? can you provide some sample of that line?

Comment: Yes I think so @AbhijitPritam because all Handlers-kbd event is in third column. I already provided you event sample and uploaded at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WspxXKljG8pOQPpb4eL91eepvRkbC4lFHXUfGEKoYzk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have modified my answer try with that

Comment: hello @AbhijitPritam thanks for your nice support. My problem is still not solved. From your given suggestion i got event0 in buttondevice file but it is not necessary my gpio-keys Handler-key always be event0 it can be anything like event0, event1,event2 etc.. So how can i make my script more generic. Please if you have any suggestion then please help me figure out this .I am stuck from past two days... :-(

Comment: @AtmaPrakash, I have modified my answer. This will work for you. I already tested in my system. Let me know if working for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

> i am still not able to get anything in buttondevce

That's no wonder, since in the input line

```
H: Handlers=kbd event0
```

there's nowhere the `evbug` your `awk` script is looking for.

> I my case it is event0 but it may vary also depends on how kernel allows.

If *it is event0* or similar, then it's nonsensical to look for `evbug`. Change the statement

```
if($i=="evbug")printf($(i-1))
```

to

```
if ($i~"event") print $i
```

(using regular expression match).

> I have rewritten my script like above. but through it, I have got two events(event0, event3) but … my input devices are many but i want the gpio-keys event

Aha - in order to take only the handler line from the `gpio-keys` section, you can use `sed` with an address range:

```
  EVENT=`sed -n '/gpio-keys/,/Handlers=kbd/s/.*Handlers=kbd //p' </proc/bus/input/devices`
```

Comment: Hello @Armali Thanks. Please look at my uploaded log file https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WspxXKljG8pOQPpb4eL91eepvRkbC4lFHXUfGEKoYzk/edit?usp=sharing. So what will  you suggest instead writing of evbug.

Comment: @Atma Prakash - See above.

Comment: if  grep -q  "gpio-keys" /proc/bus/input/devices  ; then
    #EVENT=$(cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep "Handlers=kbd")
    EVENT=$(cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep "Handlers=kbd" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if ($i~"event") print $i } }')
    #foo=$(echo "$EVENT" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~"event") print $i}')
    #foo=${EVENT:(-7)}
    echo -n "$EVENT" > /home/ubuntu/buttonDevice
fi

Comment: hello @Armali  I have rewritten my script like above. but through it, I have got two events(event0, event3) but in as i mentioned on https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WspxXKljG8pOQPpb4eL91eepvRkbC4lFHXUfGEKoYzk/edit?usp=sharing link my input devices are many but i want the gpio-keys event from my script so please help me to figure out it. Thanks